# gst-launch equivalent for gst-play

Tags: gstreamer

Is it possible to get `gst-launch` string equivalent for any `gst-play` command?

For example, playing rtsp stream with `gst-play` could be:

> ```
> gst-play-1.0.exe rtsp://path/to/source
> ```

That command makes connect to server and opens internal (gstreamer) window for playing.

Equivalent command could be (I don't really sure):

> ```
> gst-launch-1.0.exe uridecodebin uri=rtsp://path/to/source ! autovideosink
> ```

But how to get it in general case?

My main purpose is to redirect video stream to an avi-file while I know only good `gst-play` command. So I need to replace `autovideosink` with `filesink` in result command.

Comment: btw your update totaly changed the question.. it has nothing to do with gst-play versus gst-launch.. you should have asked about the replacement of the sink in another question.. never change the question in the way that it has nothing in common with previous version - always open up new question

Comment: @otopolsky my question have been updated as soon as I realized (duration ~1 hour) what I want to see in answer. You answer was posted after my final edit.

Comment: yeah, anyway it applies.. the first one was good question as well :)
and it seems that you got answer for the first version of your question - so it makes sense to open up another one.. it doesnt matter in this case, but in the futer it may help you and others. The other thing is that your title does not correspond with what you want to ask

Comment: @otopolsky the world is not perfect ... my question too :)

Comment: @otopolsky I have another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003288/save-rtsp-stream-into-avi-file-with-gstreamer) with opened bounty, so you can try to answer if it's seems interesting for you.

Answer (score 3):

After update - I would say that you have some options:

1, Use gst-play with option --videosink but you would also need the avi mux element there and also it must be encoded in h264.. so this approach would need some hacking in source code of gst-play which you obviously do not want

1a, You can also use playbin as suggested by @thiagoss with parameter video-sink .. then you can maybe use named bin and pass it to it (not sure if this is possible this way, but you may try this):

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp video-sink=bin_avi \( name=bin_avi x264enc ! avimux ! filesink location=file.avi \)
```

2, Get the pipeline picture, analyse it and create the same thing yourself manually, in Unix-like systems do:

```
export GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=`pwd`
gst-play-1.0 rtsp://... 
#or use gst-launch and playbin.. its the same thing basically
```

Check the generated *.dot files.. choose the latest one (in PLAYING state) and use graphviz library to turn it into picture:

```
dot -T png *PLAYING.dot -o playbin.png
```

3, Use just the uridecodebin stuff and continue like I wrote in 1a

```
uridecodebin ! video/x-raw ! x264enc ! ....
```

HTH

Comment: 1a. gives me `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not set property "video-sink" in element "playbin0" to "bin_avi"`. In my case I have `MP4V-SE` codec for video and `PCMU` for audio, and as I see there is no `x263enc` (for MPEG4 part 2).

Comment: 2. `*.dot` files don't created for `gst-play`, only for `gst-launch`. Graph on the picture becomes quite complicated and incomprehensible for me.

Comment: @alexolut well can you paste it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Use playbin:

`gst-launch-1.0.exe playbin uri=rtsp://path/to/source`

Comment: Thanks. But I forgot something important. Question updated.