# Save rtsp stream into avi file with gstreamer

Tags: video, save, gstreamer, rtsp, mpeg-4

I have a video server which gives me a video & audio streams over rtsp. I can see it using gstreamer tool `gst-launch` with command:

> ```
> gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://path/to/source ! autovideosink
> ```

Now I need to store that video stream into file for subsequent playback in any popular video player (VLC, Windows Media Player and so on).

I tried simply replace `autovideosink` with `filesink location=file.avi` and add `-e` option like recommended in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25949095/3240681). File created but I think it's no in correct video format (VLC can't play it).

Also I tried command from recently referenced answer:

> ```
> gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://path/to/source ! decodebin !
> x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=file.avi
> ```

It gives me error:

> ```
> ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
> Additional debug info:
> gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
> streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
> ```

The reason is (as I think) `x264enc ! mp4mux` is for H.264 codec, but [my device](http://www.moxa.com/doc/specs/VPort_254_Series.pdf) works only in MPEG4 part2 mode (MP4V-ES, i.e. H.263). So I need to replace some elements in pipeline to satisfy abilities of my device . But by looking in [gstreamer plugins list](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html) I can't found any suitable for MP4V-ES (H.263).

And now my question is: how to modify gst-launch command to save video from my slightly old device into file to further playing?

Full log for command with verbosity:

> `gst-launch-1.0 -e -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.101.44/moxa-cgi/multicaststream_ch1_stream1 ! decodebin ! avenc_mpeg4 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=file.mp4`

> ```
> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
> Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
> Progress: (open) Opening Stream
> Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.101.44/moxa-cgi/multicaststream_ch1_stream1
> Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
> Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
> Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager: latency = 2000
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager: ntp-sync = false
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager: use-pipeline-clock = false
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager: drop-on-latency = false
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager: buffer-mode = Slave receiver to sender clock
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: timeout = 5000000000
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:9068): GStreamer-WARNING **: gstpad.c:4555:store_sticky_event:<udpsrc1:src> Sticky event misordering, got 'caps' before 'stream-start'
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0: ttl = 128
> Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc2: timeout = 5000000000
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc3.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc3: caps = application/x-rtcp
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:9068): GStreamer-WARNING **: gstpad.c:4555:store_sticky_event:<udpsrc3:src> Sticky event misordering, got 'caps' before 'stream-start'
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc3.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager.GstGhostPad:recv_rtcp_sink_1.GstProxyPad:proxypad5: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpSession:rtpsession1.GstPad:sync_src: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpSsrcDemux:rtpssrcdemux1.GstPad:rtcp_sink: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpSession:rtpsession1.GstPad:recv_rtcp_sink: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager.GstGhostPad:recv_rtcp_sink_1: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSink:udpsink2: ttl = 128
> Progress: (open) Opened Stream
> Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
> New clock: GstSystemClock
> Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
> Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
> Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: timeout = 0
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc2: timeout = 0
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpSession:rtpsession0.GstPad:send_rtcp_src: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_0: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSink:udpsink1.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad3: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpSession:rtpsession1.GstPad:send_rtcp_src: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_1: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSink:udpsink3.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_1.GstProxyPad:proxypad6: caps = application/x-rtcp
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_src_1_109102090_0: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)0, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU, encoding-params=(string)1, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)2318609, seqnum-base=(uint)26256, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_src_1_109102090_0: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)0, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU, encoding-params=(string)1, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)2318609, seqnum-base=(uint)26256, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad0: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)0, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU, encoding-params=(string)1, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)2318609, seqnum-base=(uint)26256, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)0, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU, encoding-params=(string)1, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)2318609, seqnum-base=(uint)26256, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)0, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU, encoding-params=(string)1, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)2318609, seqnum-base=(uint)26256, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)0, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU, encoding-params=(string)1, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)2318609, seqnum-base=(uint)26256, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_src_1_109102090_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad8: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)0, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU, encoding-params=(string)1, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)2318609, seqnum-base=(uint)26256, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_src_1_109102090_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad7: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)0, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU, encoding-params=(string)1, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)2318609, seqnum-base=(uint)26256, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstRtpPcmuDepay:rtppcmudepay0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-mulaw, channels=(int)1, rate=(int)8000
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMuLawDec:mulawdec0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-mulaw, channels=(int)1, rate=(int)8000
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstRtpPcmuDepay:rtppcmudepay0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)0, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU, encoding-params=(string)1, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)2318609, seqnum-base=(uint)26256, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMuLawDec:mulawdec0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)8000, channels=(int)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad9: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)8000, channels=(int)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_src_0_2387976809_96: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)3, config=(string)000001B003000001B50900000100000001200088400668582120A31F, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)26503772, seqnum-base=(uint)15792, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_src_0_2387976809_96: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)3, config=(string)000001B003000001B50900000100000001200088400668582120A31F, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)26503772, seqnum-base=(uint)15792, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_src_0_2387976809_96.GstProxyPad:proxypad11: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)3, config=(string)000001B003000001B50900000100000001200088400668582120A31F, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)26503772, seqnum-base=(uint)15792, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstRtpBin:manager.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_src_0_2387976809_96.GstProxyPad:proxypad10: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)3, config=(string)000001B003000001B50900000100000001200088400668582120A31F, a-tool=(string)"MOXA\ 4CH\ Streamming\ Server\ V1.0", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"4CH\ Streaming", x-qt-text-inf=(string)/dev/at2042, clock-base=(uint)26503772, seqnum-base=(uint)15792, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1
> ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
> Additional debug info:
> gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
> streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
> EOS on shutdown enabled -- waiting for EOS after Error
> Waiting for EOS...
> ```

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> pressed here.

> ```
> handling interrupt.
> Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
> Interrupt while waiting for EOS - stopping pipeline...
> Execution ended after 0:00:12.942466327
> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
> Setting pipeline to READY ...
> Setting pipeline to NULL ...
> Freeing pipeline ...
> ```

Also you can look at diff for "good" (save to file works) with "bad" (error occured) on [this link](http://www.mergely.com/3Ze5PsQF/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera you have seems to be producing MPEG4 Type 2 streams which you are trying to wrap up in a mp4 container. So the x264_enc attempt will not work as the stream type is incompatible. Secondly you cannot use a MP4 mux with an AVI file type as with your other attempt though you can try avimux for that. Breaking down the stream which works well from the caps negotiation we can construct it as:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://path/to/source ! rtpmp4vdepay ! mpeg4videoparse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

The `rtpmp4vdepay`, `mpeg4videoparse` and the `mp4mux` are typically wrapped up in the `decodebin` element itself but just to make our life easier and to see what is going wrong it is always good to lay the elements out. It gives you control over the pipeline you are constructing rather than leaving it to the caps negotiation to figure that out which I would not recommend for IP Cameras.

I would also recommend trying out the pipeline (avoid the decodebin for IP cameras though):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://path/to/source ! decodebin ! avenc_mpeg4 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=file.mp4
```

Having said that [this link](http://www.mergely.com/3Ze5PsQF/) posted in the original question, shows the different negotiation formats when trying to play the stream. For example the one which 'works' trys to add elements in the order mentioned in the working pipline above and the non-working one try's to negotiate a different format by adding rtppcmudepay element. I think it would be down to the camera which is making the decodebin think that there is more than one type of stream available and the decodebin aims to resolve those caps by adding additonal elements which are not required.

Comment: The command in the last line is same as in my answer (except file extension). It works only in ~10% cases. I.e. there are some incomprehensible difference between `decodebin ! avenc_mpeg4` and `rtpmp4vdepay ! mpeg4videoparse` chains. If you know it, that would be cool to reflect it in the answer.

Comment: Edited with more info - can you please add your camera type to the original question maybe for someone else who faces a similar issue. thanks :)

Comment: Link to pdf documentation for my video-server (not a camera) already in body of question. Each of 4 channels contains video+audio streams. I don't need the audio stream (because no microphone). But I think `gst-play` does receive audio stream too. Don't know how to check it existence without a real audio source.

Comment: I have used the MOXA device before, I think you can login to the configuration webpage of the device and disable the audio.

Comment: It's old device, configuration only possible with MS IE6. And I can't find any option to disable audio stream at all.

Comment: There is mention of this here: http://support.elmark.com.pl/moxa/products/Serwery_video/VPort_254/manual/VPort_254_UM_1e.pdf see page 3-4

Comment: Client settings affect only to in-browser view. E.g. I set `video only` for channel 1. Then open rtsp location for that channel in VLC player. Go to codec info (ctrl+j), see stream0 (video) + stream1 (audio).

Comment: I guess if you have no audio input it should be fine.

Comment: Silent audio stream gives some amount of extra data anyway. And possibly its existence - the reason of buggy `decodebin ! avenc_mpeg4` chain.

Comment: It does yes, you can always add a tee and route the audio to a fakesink. The above would also be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using `avenc_mpeg4` instead of `x264enc` works for me. The final command is:

> `gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://path/to/source ! decodebin ! avenc_mpeg4 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=file.avi`

It works. But only 1 time of ~10. Other 9 times I got same error as in the question:

> streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)

I don't know what is the real reason for it. But I think it's device feature.

However, command like:

> `gst-play-1.0 rtsp://path/to/source`

works stable, i.e. without errors.

Comment: before the 'not linked' message it should say which pad or which element is not linked can you please paste that too?

Comment: @SamerTufail you can see it in question.

Comment: I was trying to link the bottom to the top so I missed that, apologies. Can you try running your pipeline with a '-v' along with the '-e' and share the output?

Comment: @SamerTufail log added.

Comment: Can you try this: gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://path/to/source ! rtpmp4vdepay ! mpeg4vparse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=file.avi

Comment: @SamerTufail `erroneous pipeline: no element "mpeg4vparse"`

Comment: Sorry, its mpeg4videoparse, gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://path/to/source ! rtpmp4vdepay ! mpeg4videoparse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4 - for mpeg4 streams
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://path/to/source ! rtpmp4vdepay ! mpeg4videoparse ! avimux ! filesink location=test.avi - for avi streams

Comment: First one works well. Second one gives error `streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)`.
Can you describe in a separate answer whats wrong was in my try, and why your code works? If you do this, I could accept it.

Comment: Thanks I will add that to the answer with an explanation as to why this is happening.